Determining a geometric angle
I have the following situation  where the line $(AB)$ is orthogonal to the "vertical line" passing through $C$.
Is there a way to determine the blue angle in terms of $\boldsymbol {AC}$, $\boldsymbol{BC}$ and the red angle, or is there a degree of freedom?
I only get the equation (where $b$ is the blue angle and $r$ is the red angle)
$$AC \cos(b) = BC \cos(b+r)$$
But this does not give any explicit expression for the blue angle. Is there any?

Something is unclear to me. If $CA$ is orthogonal to the vertical line, it means that the blue angle is $90^\circ$. I think you misunderstood the problem somewhere.

@Andrei Indeed, I meant $(AB)$, I corrected the mistake in the OP

We can see immediately that it’s solvable since the given data determine the triangle ABC uniquely. The rest is just angle chasing.

I assume you meant that $AB$ is orthogonal to the line passing thru $C$. Let the $\alpha$ is the blue angle. We have that $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}-\angle{CBA}-\angle{ACB}$. You can find $AB$ using law of cosines: $AB=\sqrt{CA^2+BC^2-2 CA\cdot BC \cdot \cos \angle{ACB}}$ Then find $\angle{CBA}$ using law of sines: $\frac{AB}{\sin \angle{ACB}}=\frac{AC}{\sin \angle{CBA}}$

Inputing all together, letting $\beta = \angle{ACB}$, I get $\alpha = \pi/2 - \beta - \mathrm{arcsin}(AC\sin(\beta)/\sqrt{AC^2 + BC^2 - 2AC\cdot BC\cos(\beta)})$, which is indeed an explicit formula as I wanted. Thank you! I am a bit bothered, since when $AC = BC$, I should get that $\alpha = \beta/2$, right? However, in this case, I cannot recover the result from the formula... (I recover $1/2$ in the arcsine function, hence a value of $\pi/6$ as a result)

@Wirdspan: as $\alpha < \alpha + \beta$, it's impossible to have $AC=BC$ in this configuration. If you mean $AC=AB$, this still does not guarantee $\alpha = \beta /2$, just that $\alpha= \pi/2-2 \beta$

@Wirdspan: If $\beta = \pi/6$ and $AC=AB$ you can verify that $\alpha = \beta$

So the formula/proof is deeply different when $A$ is on the left of the perpendicular line, or is it just a matter of sign?

If $A$ and $B$ are not on the same side regarding the line,  the formula will be different (sum of two angles minus the right angle). So yeah, multiple the result by by $-1$ in that case.

@Vasili had a great approach.Time for my bit simpler contribution.
Let the unknown angle be $\alpha$.
$$(AC\cos \alpha)^2+(AC\sin \alpha + AB)^2=BC^2$$
Hence
$$2ACAB\sin \alpha =BC^2-AB^2-AC^2$$
$$\implies \alpha =\arcsin\bigg(\frac{BC^2-AB^2-AC^2}{2ACBC}\bigg)$$
